# Javadoc: link to method with default argument

Tags: javadoc

I have two method, where one method is a simple proxy for the other with some default argument:

```
/**
 * do the foo
 * @param bar preprocess object baz
 * @param baz the object we are working on
 */
public void foo(boolean bar, Object baz) {}

/**
 * do the foo, with preprocessing.
 * See {@link #foo(boolean, Object)}
 * @param baz the object we are working on
 */
public void foo(Object baz) {
    foo(true, baz);
}
```

Here, the second method *foo(Object)* is a convenience shortcut for *foo('true', Object).

**Q**: How can I state this in javadoc? I mean replacing "`See {@link #foo(boolean, Object)}`" with something like `{@link #foo(true, Object)`? (The latter version however is syntactically incorrect.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe `@link` construct allows you to display arbitrary text while still linking to the proper Java element:

```
/**
 * do the foo, with preprocessing.
 * See {@link #foo(boolean, Object) foo(true, Object)}
 * @param baz the object we are working on
 */
public void foo(Object baz) {
    foo(true, baz);
}
```